Is there any way to play a raw binary sound (List<int> data) in Flutter Flame?
I want to generate my own sound waves on the fly rather than loading them from files (trying to simulate the sound chip of the C64)
I've been going in circles all day.
Here's where I'm at.
I can generate a sound - that part is easy.
I converted the sound into PCM and made it a WAV by adding the header and have the result as a List. I dumped it onto disk and, yes, it plays fine. So that part is done.
I tried flame_audio
FlameAudio can't do binary, it can only read from the asset folder as far as I can see. Since it needs to be an asset, I can only play preloaded files, so with FlameAudio.play("sound") I can't generate a dynamic sound.
I tried the underlying audioplayer:
AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
await player.play(source);

That's not working because it seems AudioPlayer needs to be called from the UI loop, ie I get this error "channel sent a message from native to Flutter on a non-platform thread."
However I need to call play from the Flutter Flame update loop.
I cannot get a sound to play and I get those thread errors.
I tried using the AudioPlayer from FlameAudio and also as standalone.
I tried flutter_sound and reading the data as a stream await
flutterSound.startPlayerFromStream(data);

I can't recall the errors now, but that was a no go as well.
just_audio doesn't seem to be able to only read from file or url.
Does anyone have an example how to make this happen?
